# Situations to (not) use lazy pattern matching on tuples

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

From what I can understand, lazy pattern matching on tuples is just deferring the resolving of the `(,)` constructor...if we use the two fields immediately, is there really any downside?  It will be resolved anyway...

Is there any reason to *not* use the lazy pattern match?

```
foo ~(x, y) = x + y
-- vs
foo (x, y)  = x + y
```

When would you ever prefer to use the second?

EDIT: I'm specifically interested in the case where there will only be one pattern and the pattern will always match.

Answer (score 8):

You wouldn’t want to use lazy pattern matching if you wanted to do any strict matching inside the lazy pattern. For example, given these definitions:

```
foo' (Just x, Just y) = Just (x + y)
foo' _ = Nothing

foo ~(Just x, Just y) = Just (x + y)
foo _ = Nothing
```

`foo' (Just 5, Nothing)` gives `Nothing`, but `foo (Just 5, Nothing)` throws a runtime error—and additionally gives a compile-time warning that the `_` case is redundant because the `~(…)` case is irrefutable.

It pretty much only makes sense to use lazy pattern matching when you know the pattern will always match, basically meaning that you’re only using single-constructor types such as `(,)` throughout the lazy pattern.

Comment: Hi, this is a good answer, but I think I am more interested in the case where I'm going to be matching no matter what, and there will only ever be one pattern.  If that's the case, when *shouldn't* i use the lazy pattern match?

Answer (score 7):

One example is the State monad. The strict/lazy versions of the State monad are distinguished by how they pattern-match on the (value, state) pair during binds.

[Strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html#state) State monad:

```
m >>= k  = StateT $ \ s -> do
    (a, s') <- runStateT m s
    runStateT (k a) s
```

[Lazy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#state) State monad:

```
m >>= k  = StateT $ \ s -> do
    ~(a, s') <- runStateT m s
    runStateT (k a) s'
```

The lazy pattern match in the lazy State monad lets you define strange programs  like this one (taken from [this blog post](http://blog.melding-monads.com/2009/12/30/fun-with-the-lazy-state-monad/) at Melding Monads):

```
pro :: State [Bool] ()
pro = do
   pro
   s <- get
   put (True : s)
```

The program generates a lazy infinite list of `True` values using "head recursion". The same program using the strict State monad would blow the stack before generating anything.

Comment: So...why can't we always use the lazy one?  When is the strict one preferred?

Comment: The performance of the lazy bind given above is truly terrible for typical (i.e. non-exotic) use cases.   In my past experience,  using the strict bind instead often speeds up programs by a factor of anywhere from 10x to 50x.

Comment: @lpsmith so you're saying that it's *always* preferred, unless you want bottoms to be okay?

Comment: Well,  in the case of the state monad, I would say as fairly firm rule of thumb,  yes.   I would be interested in any exceptions that you might discover.

In the context of your original question, however,  the performance difference is often not nearly so dramatic.   For whatever reasons,  the lazy state monad is a particularly pathological case,  at least when used from a typical imperative mindset.

Answer (score 2):

Laziness has performance costs. Sometimes, it has performance benefits. There's a reason the strict `State` monad danidiaz mentions exists; delaying and delaying means eventually you may run out of memory, or get bad cache performance. You have to think about what's going on in each case. A good rule of thumb is that pattern matches should be strict unless there's a specific reason to make them lazy. When in doubt, or when performance is critical, try benchmarking and/or profiling with both ways.

Answer (score 0):

An example where `~` is needed: Thanks to laziness, you can fold over an infinite structure like this to get the first element:

```
foldMap (First . Just) [(1::Int)..]
```

However, if you want use the `Monoid` instance of `(a, b)` to compute two such results at once, it fails:

```
foldMap (\x -> (First (Just x), First (Just x))) [(1::Int)..]
```

never finishes. The reason is non-lazy pattern match in the definition of `mappend` for `(,)`:

> ```
>  instance (Monoid a, Monoid b) => Monoid (a,b) where
>     mempty = (mempty, mempty)
>     (a1,b1) `mappend` (a2,b2) = (a1 `mappend` a2, b1 `mappend` b2)
> ```

However, defining the same monoid with lazy matching as

```
newtype LazyTuple a b = LazyTuple (a, b)
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

instance (Monoid a, Monoid b) => Monoid (LazyTuple a b) where
    mempty = LazyTuple (mempty, mempty)
    LazyTuple (~(x1, y1)) `mappend` LazyTuple (~(x2, y2))
      = LazyTuple (x1 <> x2, y1 <> y2)
```

works as expected:

```
foldMap (\x -> LazyTuple (First (Just x), First (Just x))) [(1::Int)..]
```

finishes immediately.